# Amcharts custom class for graph

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible add custom classes for am charts each graph so that i can change the style via style sheets rather than giving the style in JavaScript.

like

```
<g transform="translate(66,20)" class="amcharts-graph-smoothedLine amcharts-graph-graphAuto0_1479112833659 my_class_name">
```

Comment: FYI a nice overview [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/css-class-names/). First google entry by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, provide an id to the graph, if you provide id as test then the graph will have a class 'amcharts-graph-test'.